# Can't install php5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, php, 16.04

so I've recently installed my first Ubuntu, to be precise, a daily build of 16.04, on my new laptop since the hardware was to new for 15.10. Now I'm in the process of setting it up and I want to install php5 and some extensions.

When I execute `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` I get the error message that there is no installation package available for php5 and libapache2.

The error message is in german, so I doubt that this would help, but anyways here it is. :-)
`E: For package »libapache2-mod-php5« existiert kein Installationskandidat.`

Do I need to add a apt-get repository? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04/756186#756186

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install different or more recent PHP versions in supported Ubuntu releases? (like 5.5.x in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-or-more-recent-php-versions-in-supported-ubuntu-relea)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

*TL;DR: If you want to stay with php5, you will need to stay at Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*

**Using PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

Ubuntu 16.04 has switched to PHP 7.0 with a new infrastructure for PHP package.  So, no, you can't install php5 on Ubuntu 16.04, but you can install PHP 7.0 packages with:

`apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

That will install a virtual package that depends on the latest PHP version and pull `libapache2-mod-php7.0` as a dependency.

If you are looking for extensions, always use a version-less variant as well (e.g. `php-apcu` instead of `php7.0-apcu`) as the PECL extensions are packaged without the version to allow smooth upgrades.

**Using PHP PPA to coinstall PHP 5.6 with PHP 7.0**

There's an option to co-install PHP 5.6 packages using `ppa:ondrej/php`.

For more information, please see that answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/762161/309221

Extracted from link above:

> Assuming `libapache2-mod-php` is a suitable way to enable PHP in Apache for you, you can proceed in this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

> **Switch PHP version** ( Apache ):
>
> - from php5.6 to php7.0:
>     `sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart`
> - from php7.0 to php5.6:
>     `sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: No, there are no PHP 5.x packages in Xenial repositories. Only in the PPA.

Comment: Looks like you're right: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1522422

Comment: When I switch to php5.6, I got error "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.".

Comment: And what does the journal say?

Comment: found something like this apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /e

Comment: Then fix the configuration error...  this is not something you should be solving in the comments section here.

Comment: But it's ok if I switch to php7. This problem only happens when I switch to php5.6.

Comment: Can we trust the non auth pkgs?
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libssl1.0.2 php-common php5.6-common php5.6-json php5.6-opcache php5.6-readline php5.6-cli libapache2-mod-php5.6 php5.6

Comment: Something is broken on your system, remove the PPA and add it back again.

Comment: 5.6 is also possible for 16+ version: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6`

Comment: $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
ALSO THIS:
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php5.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libapache2-mod-php5.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libapache2-mod-php5.6'

Comment: Anyone else getting **`Module php5.6 does not exist`** when running `a2enmod php5.6`? I installed the following: `sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-curl php5.6-gd php5.6-xml php5.6-xmlrpc libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0`

Answer (score 25):

EDIT: the accepted answer does not explicitly say how to co-install PHP 5.6 and 7.0, so I wanted to extend it.

For more information, please see that answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/762161/309221

Extracted from link above:

> Assuming `libapache2-mod-php` is a suitable way to enable PHP in Apache for you, you can proceed in this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

> **Switch PHP version** ( Apache ):
>
> - from php5.6 to php7.0:
>     `sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart`
> - from php7.0 to php5.6:
>     `sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: FYI: The PPA you use is maintained by the person who wrote the accepted answer. And the last line in that answer: "There's an option to co-install PHP 5.6 packages using ppa:ondrej/php". Note that you aren't installing php5 packages either, but php5.6

Comment: There are a number of differences in the packaging and location of configuration files that anyone looking for the old php5 packages would be surprised in the new ones.

Comment: I have edited my answer so it doesn't say that the accepted answer was incorrect, but only extends it.

Comment: @NoBugs It does have imagick extension packaged. Please stop spewing things without at least basic checking whether they are true or not.

Comment: @FlavioEscobar I have merged your edits into my answer. Thanks for extending the answer.

Comment: @oerdnj Apparently purging that ppa *does not remove packages from that ppa...* and since it seems they did decide to not include 5.x, you are correct, my mistake.

Comment: but how switch it for CLI

Comment: I am confused by the words 'EDIT: the accepted answer does not explicitly say how to co-install PHP 5.6 and 7.0, so I wanted to extend it.' I cannot see any reference to co installing or any reference to PHP 7.  It seems to me a simpler answer would be to explain you can no longer install php5 and need to install php 5.6 - no offence intended - just curious.