# Owncloud 7 Migration from Ubuntu 12.04 to 16.04

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, php, migration, owncloud-server

folks,

I have a Ubuntu 12.04. Server with Owncloud 7.0.4.2 on it. 
I want to migrate to a 16.04 machine and then upgrade to oc 9.
Updating the old owncloud 7 before migration does not work on ubuntu 12.04.
Since I need the same version for migration, I need to install oc 7 on the ubuntu 16.04 server.
Unfortunately, this is not possible either because Owncloud 7 needs php5 and there are no installation candidates available on ubuntu 16.04.

How can I do this in a proper way? Do I need to migrate it to an ubuntu 14.04 first, then update and then migrate to ubuntu 16.04?

Best Greetings

***Update (27.3.17):*** The solution for me was to install php5.6 on the ubuntu 16.04 machine with the ondrej repo (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. You should upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 first, then upgrade again to 16.04. This is the proper way to do things.

If you have physical access to the server, you could load 16.04 on a USB drive, boot from it, and then upgrade directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I do not know if I described the problem correctly, though. I do have two virtual machines, one with Ubuntu 12.04. and one with Ubuntu 16.04. which is empty at the moment. Do you still recommend migrating to a new virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 on it?

I also have to note that it is important to have as little downtime as possible, because the userbase is rather big (>200 users)

Comment: Oh dear. I misunderstood. I wrote my answer in the mindset that you were upgrading a single machine, not moving to one that was already upgraded. I'm guessing migrating to 14.04, then to 16.04 would still be the best option. You could try manually downloading and installing the php5 package on 16.04, but that might need other dependencies, which would turn into a gigantic mess.

Comment: I managed to install PHP5 besides PHP7 like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04.
Then, it said that a few php-modules were missing (zip, XMLwriter, dom, libxml, GD, SimpleXML). I installed them (sudo apt install php5.6-zip php5.6-XMLwriter php5.6-GD) and the installation wizard appeared when visiting the site. Looks fine so far. This worked with the Tar file for oC7.0.15 from https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-7.0.15.tar.bz2. Next step is to just copy all files of /var/www/owncloud from old machine to new one and use a mysql dump...;)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I didn't want to suggest manually installing php5, because I didn't know how complicated the dependencies were going to be, but it looks like you got it working just fine.