# Error in installation of dvwa

Tags: 16.04, mysql, php, security

```
Sudo apt-get install unzip apache2 php5 php5-mysql php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5 is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5-mysql is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

### THIS WAS THE ERROR SHOWN

Comment: What do you expect to install with php5 and php5-mysql?

Comment: Expected behavior: php5* packages were dropped after 15.04. Your package list works only in Ubuntu 14.04 now. Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yeah, now it is working there was a problem in the php version as php 5.6 is not supporting in ubuntu 16.04.